# How to merge cell using closedxml with a dynamic column count?

Tags: c#, closedxml

This is how to merge cell using ClosedXML based on the documentation.

```
worksheet.Range("B2:D3").Row(1).Merge();
```

My problem is my column count is dynamic, I can't set column letter value to merge because i will based the merging of cell on my gridview column count.

Anyone who can help me to merge cell using closedXML?

Comment: Please play fair and mark the question as answered if you're happy with the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I do it this way

```
int row = 1;
int col = 1;

worksheet.Range(worksheet.Cell(row, col++), worksheet.Cell(row, col++)).Merge();
```

Answer (score 1):

Build up the range as a variable based on your column count and pass the variable to the `Range` method. You don't need to HAVE to pass a hard coded value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the code below?

```
 worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = "Title";
 var range = worksheet.Range("A1:F1");
 range.Merge().Style.Font.SetBold().Font.FontSize = 16;
```

It works for me.

Comment: This is the same code as the question `.Range("A1:F1")` - maybe read the question?

Comment: Yeah I don't believe this answer provides additional context over the original question. One answer suggestion could be the following, where X is the amount of cells to merge on the given row: ```worksheet.Range(worksheet.Cell(row, col), worksheet.Cell(row, col + X)).Merge();```